# Filtrar elementos recursivamente

Tags: python, python-3.x, codificación

Tengo el siguiente programa con una función recursiva la cual debe devolver una nueva lista conteniendo los nombres de la lista pasada como primer parámetro que empiecen por la letra pasada como segundo parámetro. La salida debe ser `['Martin,'Max','Mia']` y la salida que a mi me devuelve es `None`

```
import modulo_auxiliar

lista = ['John','Paul','Martin','Peter','Max','Mia']
letra = 'M'
llamada = modulo_auxiliar.filnombres(lista, letra)
print(filtraciones)


def filnombres(lista, letra):
    lista1 = []
    if letra in lista:
        lista1.append(lista)
        return lista1
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes no es una función recursiva, sino una función que dice que si la letra que sea se encuentra en la lista, la agregue a la lista1 y luego devuelva la lista con ese solo elemento. Es decir, que si uno de los elementos de la lista fuera sólo 'M', lo añadiría a la lista y la devolvería así: `['M']`. Como ninguno de los elementos que le has pasado dentro de la lista es así, te devuelve `None`, porque nunca se llega a entrar en el código dentro del `if` y, por lo tanto la función no devuelve nada.

Prueba esto:

```
# import modulo_auxiliar
def filnombres(lista, letra):
    lista1 = []
    for palabra in lista:
        if palabra[0] == letra:
            lista1.append(palabra)
    return lista1

lista = ['John','Paul','Martin','Peter','Max','Mia']
letra = 'M'
llamada = filnombres(lista, letra)
print(llamada)
```

Así sería la resolución usando una función recursiva:

```
# import modulo_auxiliar
def filnombres(lista, letra, lista1=[], i=0):
    if i < len(lista):
        if lista[i][0] == 'M':
            lista1.append(lista[i])
        filnombres(lista, letra, lista1, i + 1)

    return lista1

lista = ['John','Paul','Martin','Peter','Max','Mia']
letra = 'M'
llamada = filnombres(lista, letra)
print(llamada)
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda.Tengo una duda y es la siguiente: Se puede en una función recursiva usar un método iterativo como el "for..."

Comment: Sí se puede. Una función recursiva no es más que una función normal, que se llama a sí misma.

Comment: Mira, edito mi respuesta para que veas cómo sería la solución usando una función recursiva. Si he resuelto tu duda, cierra la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por su explcación. Tengo una última duda y es la siguiente: la sentencia que se encuentra en la línea 2 que es `if i < len(lista):` no entiendo la utilidad que desempeña

Comment: ¿Sería necesario una condición ''else'' en todos los casos?

Comment: Implementando dicha función me aparace un mensaje de error, tal que:             RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: La función `len()` devuelve la longitud (el número de elementos) de una colección. En este caso, el número de elementos de la lista de nombres original. Con la condicional le estamos diciendo a la función que itere hasta que el contador sea igual al número de elementos de la lista. Recuerda que en las colecciones se comienza a contar desde 0, por lo tanto, el último elemento de una lista de 10 elementos, es el 9. Se ahí el `if i < len(lista):`. Sin esta condicional se produciría un bucle infinito.

Comment: El `else` no es necesario en este caso, ya que sólo se ejecutará la línea del `return` cuando la condición del `if` de arriba no se cumpla. En ese caso, la función no se ejecutará más, pues saldremos de ella con el `return`.

Comment: En cuanto al error, me da que has cometido algún error al pegar el código. Asegúrate de que la indentación sea la correcta, sobre todo la del `return`. La he vuelto a testar y me devuelva: `['Martin', 'Max', 'Mia']`. Revisa también cómo estás llamando a la función.